# Verb zu Terraforming?

Tags: single-word-request

Das Substantiv [Terraforming](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terraforming) wurde unverändert aus dem Englischen ins Deutsche entlehnt:

> Als Gott schafft man per Terraforming bewohnbare Gebiete, in denen sich die eigenen Anhänger/Gläubigen ausbreiten können. (aus: *Die Zeit*, 21.01.2013)

Wie aber lautet das dazugehörige Verb?

Wenn ich mir andere aus dem Englischen entlehnte *-ing*-Formen anschaue – wie Walking/walken, Jogging/joggen – dann müsste das Verb terraformen lauten. Es klingt für mich aber ziemlich merkwürdig, wenn ich sage: "Gott terraformte die Erde." Oder kommt mir das nur so vor, weil mir das Wort noch unvertraut ist? Immerhin ist formen/formte ja gewöhnliches Deutsch, und es gibt auch schon [eine Handvoll Belege](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=terraformte) für dieses Verb, allerdings häufig in (schlechten?) Übersetzungen englischsprachiger Romane.

Comment: Die Erde zu terraformen ist ja auch irgendwie unsinnig, denn Terraforming ["ist die Umformung von anderen Planeten in bewohnbare erdähnliche Himmelskörper"](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terraforming). Den Mars oder Arrakis zu terraformen klingt erstens deutlich plausibler und für mich persönlich nach ganz normalem Deutsch.

Comment: Der Satz kommt mir unsinnig vor. Ich denke das Schaffen bewohnbarer Gebiete sei Terraforming, dann ist aber das "per" falsch. So wie wenn ich sagt "per Spaziergang unternahm ich eine Wanderung". Per Auto kann ich eine Reise unternehmen aber nicht per Urlaubsfahrt. "Erde" steckt auch in "terraforming" schon drin - "Gott formte die Erde" müsste also reichen. Bullshit bleibt Bullshit, auch wenn man ihn übersetzt.

Comment: @Raketenolli Der Satz ist ein Zitat aus der Zeitung. Für meine Frage ist es vollkommen irrelevant, ob du ihn unsinnig findest, ich wollte damit nur belegen, dass das Wort im Deutschen verwendet wird.

Comment: @userunknown Der Satz ist ein Zitat aus der Zeitung. Für meine Frage ist es vollkommen unerheblich, ob du ihn unsinnig findest, ich wollte damit nur belegen, dass das Wort im Deutschen verwendet wird.

Answer (score 4):

Das Verb würde eingedeutscht „terraformen“ heißen, da das Wort als zusammengesetztes Wort aus „Terra“ und „formen“ angesehen werden kann. Das erstere ist ein Lehnwort aus dem Lateinischen, was es im deutschen gibt, und das Verb „formen“ ist ebenso bereits existent, und auch eine korrekte Übersetzung von „forming, to form“. Man könnte aus „Terra“ noch „Erde“ machen, indem man es übersetzt, allerdings wird das Verb dann mehrdeutig, da es dann auch „Boden, Grund“ heißen könnte, und es heißt ja

> … Umformung von anderen Planeten in bewohnbare erdähnliche Himmelskörper

Daher ist der Bezug zur „Erde“ im Sinne von „Planet Erde“ zu wahren, was mit „Terra“ ganz gut funktioniert. „Gott terraformte die Erde“ ist demnach grammatikalisch richtig, da das Verb dann nach dem zweiten Wortteil dekliniert wird, also wie „formen“ ohne „Terra“.

Der Grund, warum in dem zitierten Satz „per Terraforming“ nicht übersetzt wurde, ist der, dass eine wörtliche Übersetzung ernsthaft schräg klingt: Es müsste dann „durch Terraformung“ heißen, wenn man ganz korrekt sein wollte. Da hört sich „per Terraforming“ einfach besser an.

Wollte man nach dem *Sinn* übersetzen, gibt es eine bessere Lösung: „Als Gott schafft man bewohnbare Gebiete, in denen sich die eigenen Anhänger/Gläubigen ausbreiten können⁠**, indem man (Gebiete des Planeten) terraformt**.“ Nebensatz anhängen, Verb korrekt deklinieren, fertig. Die Konstellation sieht man im Deutschen viel häufiger, als so etwas Holpriges wie ein Verb, das erst „eingedeutscht“ wird, um dann auch noch ein Nomen draus zu machen. Der Part in den klammern ist sogar optional, da „indem man terraformt“ ebenso korrekt ist. Der Bezug auf "die Gebiete" ist dann implizit; stattdessen ein „sie“ einzufügen, ist aber zumindest ein Mehrdeutigkeitsproblem, wenn nicht sogar ein Grammatikfehler (Bezug), da sich der Nebensatz dann auch auf „die Anhänger/die Gläubigen“ beziehen könnte, was keinen Sinn ergibt – die kann man ja nicht terraformen.

Answer (score 1):

Ich gehe davon aus, dass es für Wörter, die selbst in der Fremdsprache, aus der sie entlehnt worden sind, als "erfundene" Wörter bezeichnet werden könnten, weder eindeutige grammatikalische Regeln noch Regeln zur Rechtschreibung gibt.

Da auch "Terraforming" (laut Wikipedia) ein solches Wort ist, gilt dies natürlich auch für dieses Wort.

Dieses Wort stammt (ebenfalls laut Wikipedia) aus der Science-Fiction-Literatur und wurde im wissenschaftliche Bereich erst später verwendet.

Von daher wird es auch schwierig werden, "seriöse" deutschsprachige Texte zu finden, die dieses Wort enthalten.

Ich persönlich würde derartige Wörter nach Möglichkeit ganz oder zumindest davon abgeleitete Wörter (z.B. Verben oder Adjektive) vermeiden.

Warum?

In meiner Jugend war es bei einem sehr großen Teil der Bevölkerung üblich, ein vom Substantiv "Computer" abgeleitetes Verb "computern" zu verwenden:

> Meine Kinder **computern** gerade.
>
> Gestern waren sie auch nicht draußen, sondern sie haben den ganzen Tag **computert**.
>
> Ich will nicht, dass du **computerst**, bevor du deine Hausaufgaben gemacht hast.

Heute, nur einige Jahre später, klingen diese Sätze ungewohnt, wenn nicht gar falsch.

Im Fall von "Terraforming" würde ich, wenn es sich um eine Übersetzung aus dem Englischen handelt, nach einem geeigneten Verb suchen und das Wort "Terraforming" unverändert lassen.

Beispiel:

> Man **verändert** den Planeten mittels **Terraforming**.

Und nicht:

> Man **terraformt** den Planeten.